# HighPoint RocketRAID 2680SGL and FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, drivers

I'm trying to get my RAID controller working with FreeBSD. But it seems it's not being recognized by FreeBSD:

```
    module_register_init: MOD_LOAD (pci/rr2680, 0xc0a45b90, 0xc61f0430) error 22
    rr2680: RocketRAID 268x controller driver v1.0.08.1222 (Dec 22 2008 14:08:35)
    rr2680: no controller detected.
```

I'm a bit clueless on how to get it fixed. The server is a HP HDPC with a Pentium D.

Answer (score 2):

HighPoint has not released documents or source code for a driver, but do provide an old binary distribution. [It can be downloaded from their website](http://www.highpoint-tech.com/BIOS_Driver/rr26xx/RR268x/FreeBSD/rr268x-bsd-7.0-v1.0.08.1222.tgz). It's for FreeBSD 7.0, and others have reported it as broken for 7.2+.

It's probably not what you want to hear, but I'd recommend using a Adaptec or LSI based controller as they're both very well supported in FreeBSD (and every other OS).

Comment: That's not an option because it's incompatible with the current kernel :(

Answer (score 0):

There are driver sources for FreeBSD available on HPT site: [rr268x-freebsd-src-v1.0.08.1222.tgz](http://www.highpoint-tech.com/BIOS_Driver/rr26xx/268x/freebsd/rr268x-freebsd-src-v1.0.08.1222.tgz)
It can be compiled as a part of kernel, or as a kernel module (instruction can be found in README file, as usual)

Comment: Note: This is still ***NOT SOURCE***, it's part compiled blobs, part header files. The binary blob is still compiled for a certain version of FreeBSD and will not work under later versions without the compatibility layer. It will not work at all under previous versions. This is a disingenuous effort at best. (No offense to Rybario, unless you work for HighPoint)